# Where can I find some "must see" game development portfolios?

Tags: web, portfolio

I am trying to put together a website/portfolio and it would be great to see what others have done.

Comment: Showing off code and showing off art or design are very different.  What specifically are you looking for examples of?

Comment: I disagree, even something that is not typically a visual, such as AI, can be shown in a way that is pleasing to the eye. Example: http://processing.org/learning/topics/flocking.html

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I'd do is read "Your Portfolio Repels Jobs" by John Jones. He covers what he looks for in a portfolio, and how to ensure people actually get to the content you want them to see. Check it out here => [Your Portfolio repels jobs](http://www.thejonjones.com/2005/10/07/your-portfolio-repels-jobs/)

Don't scrimp on your design. Do. Not. If web dev isn't your thing, jump on wordpress and get a nice magazine theme. It really makes a difference. Google is your best friend here, and no - you don't have to fork out for premium themes to make an impact :)

Here's some examples to get you started - Top 14 Free Wordpress themes 2010 - wpbloghost dot net/free-wordpress-magazine-themes

Rick Pierce's portfolio is what you should aim for. Do not aim lower!

I'm also a massive fan of Pior Oberson's CV (pioroberson dot com). It was good enough to get him a job at Blizzard, so he's done something right.

I hope that helps! It certainly helped me get my foot in the door as a 3D artist.

N.B. Sorry about the spelled-out hyperlinks; new users aren't allowed to post more than one

Comment: I personally did not like Rick Pierce site at all, not sure why, maybe its more artsy then im used to?

Answer (score 2):

Even though not exactly an example, this discusses some DOs and DONTs of demo reels and portfolios for programming positions. It also discusses a few examples of existing portfolios and what was good about them and what wasn't.

[How to Make a Game Programming Demo Portfolio](https://web.archive.org/web/20180623050650/http://gamecareerguide.com/features/655/how_to_make_a_game_programming_.php?print=1)

Answer (score -2):

John D. Carmack's [portfolio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Carmack) :D

Comment: Pretty sure the question was asking about the best way to show off things, not just showing off impressive lists.